# Unable to login to UI of Ansible Tower - get error as "Failed to access user information. GET returned status: 500"

Tags: user-interface, authentication, ansible-tower

I'm receiving error:

> Failed to access user information. GET returned status: 500"

while trying to access Ansible Tower.

After I dismissed the error, it keeps prompting to login again and again.

Can Anyone suggest what can be done to troubleshoot this error?

Answer (score 0):

You should confirm all the services have properly started using

```
ansible-tower-service -status
```

or

```
ansible-tower-service -query
```